# How do I get ajax to work like the Google Map API?

Tags: php, ajax, api

I'm trying to get access to a Javascript API, I created, on other sites. The javascript is at https://ksc105.kscserver.com/query.js and it pulls ajax calls to https://ksc105.kscserver.com/suggestions.php (?action=getall). Of course using this on https://ksc105.kscserver.com/index.php works.

However I'm trying to use import that javascript into another domain site. I know cross-domain ajax calls do not work, but I supposed that if the ajax call is made from a javascript on that site that it was going to work. I supposed this based on Google's Map API. I'm pretty sure it uses ajax.

How do I get ajax to work like the Google Map API? Where any website can add my script and use its functions?

In firebug, I get the request to fire but I just get an empty return but it should not be returning empty. In IE9, I get the error "SCRIPT5: Access is denied." / "query.js, line 62 character 5".

If you go to https://ksc105.kscerver.com/index.php and type 3 or more characters in the box you should get "suggestions" much like Google Search. I need the same thing to work on any other website without a server proxy. You can use "Test" as it pulls a bunch of test data.

Comment: "This webpage is not available
The server at ksc105.kscerver.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the web service that translates a website's name to its internet address." Quoth the server, 404.

Comment: http://ksc105.kscserver.com/ https://ksc105.kscserver.com/suggestions.php?action=getall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using AJAX callbacks. jQuery does this well but as a raw example, if you load some JSON with a callback function (From a `<script>` tag) it will run the function. This is how you can use the Twitter API across sites. I.E. if you call `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&count=20&callback=handletwitter` and create a handletwitter function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handletwitter(data){
    console.log(data);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&count=20&callback=handletwitter"></script>
```

This is also known as JSONP

Comment: This made my life easier... in the future I could just reuse a script element for each call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a smart solution to do so. You can have an iFrame of width and height 0, so it won't be visible. From within it, you can load data on main page using 'parent' property. Since you are allowed to load anything in an iFrame, this should be a good solution for you.
Consider the following example (will also work on different domain).

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadData(data)
        {
            var a = document.getElementById("H");
            a.innerHTML = data;
        }
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="H">hello</div>
    <iframe src="sample.html" width="0px" height="0px">
    </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sample.html**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    <!--
    parent.loadData("I am inside iFrame");
    -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I can see where you are going... I think I just might do that!